# Are params[:controller_name][:field1] and params[:field1] the same in rails 3.1.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

For create in a controller, the data is passed into the controller in `params[:controller_name]`(controller_name could be article or product for example) We can use `params[:field1]` to access the `field1` data(WRONG!).  We know the data is passed in as `controller_name -> {field1 = A, field2 = B ...}`. Is `params[:controller_name][:field1]` the same as `params[:field1]`?

Can anyone explain? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: the right way to retrieve a field from params is `params[:controller_name][:field_name]`, the controller_name here could be for example, product or article.

`params[:field_name]` only returns nothing in our test.

Comment: If params[:field_name] only returns nothing then why did you say "We can use params[:field1] to access the field1 data."  Your descriptions are confusing.

Comment: just put WRONG after the statement.

Answer (score 1):

I think controller_name is a reserved param that always holds the name of the controller so that could explain any weird behavior you are seeing.  Try using :cname or something like that instead.

Comment: controller_name is just an example. It could be, for example, product or article.